# Google Map link to markers from external site

Tags: html, google-maps

i have a question. My website has link Show on Map that points to custom google map. That custom google map has 30ish markers, and when you click link from website, it opens that map, and focuses corresponding marker there. So you use show on map for marker 1, custom map opens and focuses marker 1 with info bubble.
link is here

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&amp;msid=202453748669122555293.0004ab5452234ae2281f9&amp;hl=hr&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=h&amp;vpsrc=6&amp;ll=44.833596,14.728954&amp;spn=0.007304,0.013733&amp;z=16&amp;iwloc=0004ad9b633f7bf6421e7&amp;" rel="external" class="button">Show on map</a>
```

[link to map](https://maps.google.com/maps/ms?msa=0&msid=202453748669122555293.0004ab5452234ae2281f9&hl=hr&ie=UTF8&t=h&vpsrc=6&ll=44.833596,14.728954&spn=0.007304,0.013733&z=16&iwloc=0004ad9b633f7bf6421e7&dg=feature)

Now, since i need to replicate that Google Map because i dont have acess to it anymore, i am wondering how to get link to certain marker? Since website doesnt have any javascript or anything regarding Goolge Maps, are those links hardcoded on custom map in source code or something? Since i know iwloc and coordiantes change on links.. But on source code of that custom map iwloc is same on 3-4 ocurrances in page.

Any help is welcome. I tryed to search here but everyone makes some javascript solution. I  want it to be like now... only link to that marker. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the specific map, open the desired infoWindow(by clicking on the marker or on an item in the sidebar) and then copy the **short URL** that will be shown when you click the share-button(in the top-right corner of the sidebar)

Comment: oh my god.. i just went to marker -> more ->send and copy link location... and thats it... i feel so stupid now. thank you sir..

Comment: There is a link "KML" in the sidebar, download the KML-file, it will contain all the data for the map